# FastAPI - mocking path function has no effect

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, fastapi, starlette

I've got a simple [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) application and I'm trying to create tests with `pytest` for it.

My goal is to test how app behaves in case of different errors.

I've got a simple healthcheck route in my app:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/health")
async def health():
    return "It's working ✨"
```

Now in my pytest module I'm trying to patch above function so that it raises different errors.
I'm using `unittest.mock` but I'm getting very strange behavior.

```py
import pytest
from unittest import mock

from fastapi import HTTPException
from starlette.testclient import TestClient

import app.api.health
from app.main import app  # this is my application (FastAPI instance) with the `router` attached


@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    with TestClient(app) as test_client:
        yield test_client


def test_simple(client):
    def mock_health_function():
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='gibberish')

    with mock.patch('app.api.health.health', mock_health_function):
        response = client.get(HEALTHCHECK_PATH)

        with pytest.raises(HTTPException):  # this check passes successfully - my exception is raised
            app.api.health.health()

    assert response.status_code != 200  # this check does not pass. The original function was called as if nothing was patched
```

Despite the fact that the exact same function is called inside the test, API test client still calls the original function when I hit the endpoint.

Why does `mock.patch` not work properly when function is not called directly in the test?

Or maybe I should approach my problem in some different way?

Comment: You have to patch the module that is imported by the sut - see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6) documentation. You are currently patching the function imported in your test instead.

Comment: Can you show how you import the mocked function in your tested code?

Comment: Just like in the question: I import whole module `import app.api.health` and then call function directly `app.api.health.health()`. (Sorry for that nesting).
`health` function is not imported anywhere else, it is just registered in the FastAPI router - and then it is called by the framework.

Comment: Hm, the patching actually looks correct in that case...

Comment: It seems that fastAPI's decorator `@route.get(...)` stores reference to the original function. Mock patches the function, but it happens after the route is already registered and the patched object has different id reference.

Comment: you are patching a coroutine (`async def ...`). `client` (the fastapi application) will call your `health()` endpoint asynchronously (with `await ...`). use [asynctest](https://asynctest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to mock coroutines

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: sam issue, did anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `monkeypatch` fixture to patch your function.

First pull out the code section you want to patch:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


def response():
    return "It's working ✨"


@app.get("/health")
async def health():
    return response()
```

Then use monkeypatch in your test

```
import pytest

from fastapi import HTTPException
from starlette.testclient import TestClient

from app import main


def mocked_response():
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='gibberish')


@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    from app.main import app

    with TestClient(app) as test_client:
        yield test_client


def test_simple(client, monkeypatch):

    monkeypatch.setattr(main, "response", mocked_response)
    resp = client.get("/health")
    assert resp.status_code == 400
    assert resp.json()["detail"] == "gibberish"
```

---

Another approach would be to use [Dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/), together with [dependencies_overrides](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/).
This probably won't work for all scenarios but for your given use case it does.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI,  Depends

app = FastAPI()


def response():
    return "It's working ✨"


@app.get("/health")
async def health(resp=Depends(response)):
    return resp
```

In your test client you can now override the dependency like this:

```
import pytest

from fastapi import HTTPException
from starlette.testclient import TestClient

from app.main import response


def mocked_response():
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='gibberish')


@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    from app.main import app
    app.dependency_overrides[response] = mocked_response

    with TestClient(app) as test_client:
        yield test_client


def test_simple(client):

    resp = client.get("/health")

    assert resp.status_code == 400
    assert resp.json()["detail"] == "gibberish"
```

---

If you need to add arguments to your response function you could make use of the closure pattern

```
def response_closure():
    def response(arg):
        return arg
    return response


@app.get("/health")
async def health(resp=Depends(response_closure)):
    return resp("It's working ✨")
```

Comment: The solution one does not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pytest
from unittest import mock

from fastapi import HTTPException
from starlette.testclient import TestClient

import app.api.health
from app.main import app  # this is my application (FastAPI instance) with the `router` attached


@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    with TestClient(app) as test_client:
        yield test_client


def test_simple(client):
    def mock_health_function():
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='gibberish')

    with mock.patch('app.api.health.health', mock_health_function):
        response = client.get(HEALTHCHECK_PATH)

        with pytest.raises(HTTPException):  # this check passes successfully - my exception is raised
            app.api.health.health()

        assert response.status_code != 200  # this check does not pass. The original function was called as if nothing was patched
```

You are using your patch as a context manager using with statement, try putting the assert statement insdie the with block as shown above, it should pass then i guess.

Let me know if that works !!

Comment: OP's code already obtains `response` within the `with` block. Given that, the value of `response.status_code` isn't going to be different whether it's evaluated inside the block or not.